# How's this answer wrong?

Tags: logic

Write the statement as an equivalent statement that does not use the if..then connective. Remember that $p\implies q \equiv \neg p\land q$. If i am tired, then I'm going to bed.

I am not tired and I'm going to bed.

Comment: It's $p\implies q \equiv \lnot p \lor q$. Not "and" but "or."

Comment: I think it may be easier to think through as implying $q \lor \neg p$ - thinking through $p$ is true ($q$ by implication) or $p$ is not true $\neg p$.

Comment: Just imagine you were a person who went to bed as soon as he felt tired. Would you spend all day in bed? Probably not.

Comment: @Stefan: There are other things to do in bed than sleep. One can easily spend all day in bed without sleeping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the given equivalence, this is indeed correct.

However the given equivalence is incorrect, and so this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have it a little mixed up. Instead of a conjunction, you should have a disjunction.

It should read: I am not tired or I'm going to bed.